# ¿Cómo generar un DataFrame con el mismo número de elementos de diferentes subgrupos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo un DataFrame de edad por personas:

```
df= 
identificador   edad
1                50
2                10
3                22
4                60
5                45
6                2
7                27
8                30
9                14
10               55
```

He definido 4 grupos: menores o iguales a 5 años, entre 5 y 20 años, entre 20 y 40 años y entre 40 y 60 años. 
Requiero crear un DataFrame que tenga el mismo número de registros de cada grupo. Ese número esta definido por el tamaño del grupo más pequeño (número de registros que cumplen la condición). En el ejemplo, el grupo de menores de 5 años tiene el menor tamaño 1: solo un registro cumple la condición. El nuevo DataFrame sería:

```
identificador       edad
    1                50
    2                10
    3                22
    6                2
```

Lo que yo hice fue crear una nueva columna con un código definido para cada grupo y con eso conocer el tamaño de cada grupo.

```
def ciclodevida(edad):
if edad <= 5: return 1
if (edad > 5 and edad <= 20 ): return 2
if (edad > 20 and edad <= 40 ): return 3
if (edad > 40 and edad <= 60 ): return 4
df['ciclo']= df['edad'].apply(ciclodevida)
ciclodevida=df.groupby('ciclo').size()
```

Luego cree un Dataframe independiente para cada grupo:

```
ciclo1 = df[df['ciclo'] == 1]
ciclo1 =ciclo1.reset_index(drop=True)
ciclo2 = df[df['ciclo'] == 2]
ciclo2 =ciclo2.reset_index(drop=True)
ciclo3 = df[df['ciclo'] == 3]
ciclo3 =ciclo3.reset_index(drop=True)
ciclo4 = df[df['ciclo'] == 4]
ciclo4 =ciclo4.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Finalmente elimine los registros en cada grupo dependiendo del tamaño del grupo 1 (el de menor tamaño) y luego uní todos los DataFrame usando concatenar

```
C2= ciclo2.drop(range(len(ciclo1), len(ciclo2), 1), axis=0)
C3= ciclo3.drop(range(len(ciclo1), len(ciclo3), 1), axis=0)
C4= ciclo4.drop(range(len(ciclo1), len(ciclo4), 1), axis=0)

final= pd.concat([C1,C2,C3,C4])
```

El código funciona pero quisiera hacerlo más eficiente, como se ve se deben hacer muchas fases (y esto se incrementa si hay más grupos). Además quisiera que se seleccionarán los registros que van a ingresar al nuevo DataFrame de cada grupo de manera aleatoria.

Alguien me puede ayudar con alguna idea? Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptualmente, lo que buscas son las primeras `n` filas de cada grupo (definido este por un intervalo) y siendo `n` la cantidad mínima de filas en todos los grupos.

En primer lugar, reproducimos tus datos:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

TESTDATA = StringIO("""identificador;edad
1;50
2;10
3;22
4;60
5;45
6;2
7;27
8;30
9;14
10;55
""")

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=";")
```

Y ahora, podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
# Generamos la nueva columna ciclo
rangos = [5, 20, 40, 60]
df['ciclo']= df['edad'].apply(lambda x: [i for i, v in enumerate(rangos, 1) if x <= v][0])

# Buscamos el valor minímo
minimo = min(df.groupby('ciclo').size())

# Nos quedamos con las filas de cada grupo hasta el mínimo calculado
print(df.groupby('ciclo').head(minimo))

   identificador  edad  ciclo
0              1    50      4
1              2    10      2
2              3    22      3
5              6     2      1
```

- `ciclo` lo generamos con una comprensión de listas: `[i for i, v in enumerate(rangos, 1) if x <= v][0]`, simplemente ubicamos el primer rango dónde la edad es menor igual al elemento al valor tope de ese rango, una forma más compacta que evita el uso de los `if`
- Luego obtenemos el valor mínimo con `min(df.groupby('ciclo').size())` es decir el tamaño del grupo más pequeño
- Por último, usamos `head(minimo)` para quedarnos con las primeras `n` filas de cada grupo

Comment: Muchisimas gracias.